# 100% Height Wrapper Between Header and Footer (with First Section Set to 100% Height)

Tags: html, css

I need to create a page where I would have a 100% wrapper between header and footer elements. The wrapper is a general content view where I will be adding templates. Apart of having the wrapper 100% height I need to have a first section in the wrapper also with 100% height.

The main problem is that I cannot position the footer relatively after the wrapper. It stays somewhere in the middle. See fiddle for example.

HTML

```
<header ui-view="header"></header> <!--Fixed Height/Relative-->
    <div id="wrapper" ui-view="wrapper"> <!--100% Height/Relative-->
        <section></section> <!--100% Height/Relative-->
        <section></section> <!--Auto Height Based On Content/Relative-->
        <section></section> <!--Auto Height Based On Content/Relative-->
    </div>
<footer ui-view="footer"></footer> <!--Fixed Height/Relative-->
```

CSS

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
html{
  height: 100%;
}
div{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
section:first-child{
  height: 100%;
}
section{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
header{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px; width: 100%; background: red;
}
footer{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px; width: 100%; background: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpdnyqt9/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the div you have around your sections is what's causing you some trouble.  Check out the snippet below.  If you place only your first section and the header in that div, you can accomplish what you want by putting height 100% on that div.

Note that without that div, your `:first-child` pseudo selector won't work because that section is no longer the first child of it's parent (header is). So I added an ID to it simply so I can reference it in the CSS.

So now the div is 100% of the height, header is a fixed height, and section1 is at 100% filling the remainder of the div.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background:green;
}
html{
  height: 100%;
}
div{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}

section {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
section#section1 {
  height: 100% !important;
}

header{
  height: 50px; width: 100%; background: red;
}
footer{
  height: 50px; width: 100%; background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
<header></header>
<section id='section1'>section1</section>
</div>
<section>section2</section>
<section>section3</section>
<footer></footer>
```

The `height:100%` you have set on the `body` is what's causing your footer element to be in the middle of the page.  Remember that '100%' is '100% of your window height', so be careful with that. Cheers.

Comment: If I remove 100% from body I lose it on the first content container I mentioned. Basically I need to have the first section 100% height and the rest set to auto.

Comment: OK, I think I have a better understanding now. I've revised my answer. Check the snippet above and see if that's what you're after.